# Proof of relation with coherent quantum states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-optics, linear-algebra, coherent-states

According to a Wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_state), The quantum state of the harmonic oscillator that minimizes the uncertainty relation with uncertainty equally distributed between X and P satisfies the equation:
$$\tag{1}
(X-\langle X\rangle)|\alpha\rangle=-i(P-\langle P\rangle)|\alpha\rangle$$
and that this implies:
$$\tag{2}
\left\langle\alpha\left|(X-\langle X\rangle)^{2}+(P-\langle P\rangle)^{2}\right| \alpha\right\rangle=1 / 2$$
But I do not see how that equality is shown. What I find is:
$$\tag{3}
\begin{array}{l}
(X-\langle X\rangle)|\alpha\rangle=-i(P-\langle P\rangle)|\alpha\rangle \\
\Rightarrow\langle X-\langle X\rangle\rangle+i\langle P-\langle P\rangle\rangle=0 \\
\Rightarrow\langle X-\langle X\rangle\rangle^{2}-\langle P-\langle P\rangle\rangle^{2}=-i 2\langle X-\langle X\rangle\rangle\langle P-\langle P\rangle\rangle=-i 2(\langle X P\rangle-\langle X\rangle\langle P\rangle)
\end{array}$$
which does not look similar to the expression claimed in the article. Can someone help show that eq. $(1)$ and eq. $(2)$ are equivalent?

Edit: One more thing about eq. $(2)$ that I do not understand is that it shows that $(\Delta X)^2+(\Delta P)^2=1/2$. However, if the uncertainty is minimum, the Heisenberg principle states that $\Delta X \Delta P=1/2$, so I would expect that $\Delta X=\Delta P=1/\sqrt{2}$ which does not follow from eq. $(2)$.

Comment: You ignored the (perhaps unconventional) rescaling of that section, where $\Delta X= \Delta P =1/2$. Try to focus on the unconventional commutator $[X,P]=iI/2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof is quite concise and elegant. You *must*, however, take note of the unconventional normalization.

Rearrange (1) as instructed, and "square" it, i.e., left-multiply it with its hermitian conjugate,
$$\tag{1}
(X-\langle X\rangle)|\alpha\rangle=-i(P-\langle P\rangle)|\alpha\rangle \leadsto \\ 
(X+iP)|\alpha\rangle=   (\langle X\rangle+i\langle P\rangle)|\alpha\rangle \leadsto \\ 
\langle \alpha|(X-iP)(X+iP)|\alpha\rangle=  \langle \alpha| (\langle X\rangle^2+\langle P\rangle^2)|\alpha\rangle \leadsto \\
\langle \alpha|(X^2 +P^2 +i[X,P])|\alpha\rangle=  \langle \alpha| (\langle X\rangle^2+\langle P\rangle^2)|\alpha\rangle .
$$
Substitute for the commutator on the l.h.s., $[X,P]=iI/2$, in this unconventional normalization, and move it to the right, while taking the constants of the r.h.s. to the left,
$$\tag{2}
\left\langle\alpha\left|(X-\langle X\rangle)^{2}+(P-\langle P\rangle)^{2}\right| \alpha\right\rangle=1 / 2 \\
\equiv   \Delta X^{2}+\Delta P^{2} =1 / 2 . $$

Now,
$$ \tag{3}
(\Delta X -\Delta P)^2\geq 0, \leadsto \\
\Delta X ^2 + \Delta P^2 \geq 2 \Delta X \Delta P \leadsto \\
1/4 \geq \Delta X \Delta P .
$$
But, ***in this normalization***, the Uncertainty principle also dictates
$\Delta X \Delta P \geq 1/4 $. Consequently $\Delta X \Delta P  = 1/4 $. Now squaring (1), you manifestly get $\Delta X =\Delta P$, hence   $$\tag {4} \Delta X =\Delta P  = 1/2 ,$$ and *not* your incorrect expression. Recall, in these conventions, $\hat a= X+iP  $, from which you may connect the expectation values to α.

Comment: Very well explained (not sure why someone gave a downvote). Can you tell me what the abbreviation  UP stands for?

Comment: Uncertainty principle!

Comment: Oops, of course. Thank you for the great explanation; it helped a lot.